# Google Photos like interaction : Pinch to change your perspective

Tags: android, photo, gesture, interaction

**Pinch to change your perspective**

By default, the new Google Photos app shows your images in a daily view, with medium-sized thumbnails arranged chronologically by date. But there are three other views available, and you can move between them simply by pinching in or out on your device's screen.

Pinch outward once from the day view, and Photos will move into what it considers the "comfortable" view -- in which the thumbnails are all significantly larger and easier to see.

Pinch inward once from the day view, meanwhile, and you'll go to a compact view with smaller thumbnails and thus many more images on the screen at a single time.

Pinch inward a second time, and you'll get the Photos app's monthly view. That shows you a bunch of tiny thumbnails arranged by month to give you a broad overview of your images and let you quickly scan through your collection.

Here is the gif [GIF ANIMATION](http://i.giflike.com/SZsNPpg.gif)

I am trying to implement the above described interaction for the photos by myself (just for learning purpose) but I couldn't find any example anywhere or code sample to begin with.

Please note that I am a beginner android developer but I would try to implement whatever the suggestions come forward.